# Laravel 5 Schedular vs Indatus Dispatcher

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have been looking at Indatus Dispatcher (https://github.com/Indatus/dispatcher) and it looks far more flexible than the built in Scheduler in Laravel 5.

For instance with Dispatcher I can:

```
...->daysOfTheMonth([1, 15])
```

To have a command execute on the 1st and 15th of every month.

From what I can see, you can't do that with Scheduler:

```
...->monthly(1, 15)
```

Which wouldn't work because that function doesn't accept any parameters.

Am I missing something or is Dispatcher much better?

Answer (score 5):

The Indatus Dispatcher is not compatible with Laravel 5. It has been discontinued, since the majority of the functionality is included in Laravel 5 by default now.

You can always run a custom cron time - so you can really do any scheduling with Laravel 5 you like:

```
...->cron('0 0 1,15 * * *')
```

Comment: Another possibility (for more complex schedules) is to use daily() and just check in the command if its the 1st or 15th of the month and return early if its not.

Comment: @imperium2335 - do you need any further information?

Comment: @TheShiftExchange Thanks, I didn't know one could simply use ->cron